# Retracting flags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging

I flagged the [first version](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/471350/1) of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/471350/55235) for obvious reasons.

After the edit, the flag is of no use.

Is it possible to retract it? If not, this is a feature request.

Assuming moderators would accept the flag if the answer hadn't suffered any changes, what's the supposed course of action on their part now, evaluating the flag on the conditions it was set or on the conditions in which they encounter the answer?

Comment: I recall from somewhere that flag reviewers are supposed to "clear as helpful when they feel that the user was genuinely trying to be helpful."

Comment: In this case, a moderator can click the option that the flag is helpful even though no further action is needed. THis option is not available for comments though.

Comment: I [asked a very similar question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/can-i-unflag-a-post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yes, you can now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags/281010#281010), both for questions and for answers: click on "flag" (below the already flagged post) and click on the dark blue button "Retract flag" below the list of flagging reasons.

Answer (score 6):

I support this feature-request, albeit with a modest priority.  It seems to me the logic might be similar to the recently implemented recanting of Close votes, so that clicking on the `flag` link a second time would display a dialog to withdraw (or, in more elaborate version, add information to) a request for moderator review.

It is probably more important here that moderator tasks are minimized than that we avoid declined flags.